# amplify auth google sign in issue

Tags: aws-amplify-cli, flutter-aws-amplify, amplify-auth-cognito

It was working before but when i opened the development enviornment after a month nothing seems to work. I have tried updating the auth from amplify-cli. checked the redirect urls for sign in signout to app://. pasted the client and secret keys for google credentials. double checked the URLs. What i see right now is the endpoint shows sign in page but when signed in it wont get back to app. this is the endpoint.  https://saamanf8e04f75-f8e04f75-devs.auth.eu-north-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=5715vmi1fro9hm6pl3t8av8mgu&redirect_uri=myapp://

any help is appreciated.

i was expecting it to sign in successfuly as usual which no longer works.